# Fastest way of doing an intersection?

Tags: python

I have two lists. The first has coordinates on the plane which represents a path, the other has coordinates on the plane which represent the score for each tile, with a score associated. I want to calculate the score of the path which is the sum of the score of each tile that the path is on. Example:

```
path = [ (3,4), (4,5) ]
plane = [ (3,4,50), (4,5,75), (6,7,100) ]
```

(The score of the path would be 50+75=125)

Speed is important. Plane has of the order of hundred elements, path has of the order of tens. I was thinking intersection of sets, like:

```
set(path).intersection( {p[:2] for p in plane} )
```

The problem is that then I'm not keeping track of the scores.

I'm sure there must be a simple way to do this.

Comment: why not save `plane` as dictionary with the tile tuple as the key? then you can just search the tile as a key in the dict and return the sum.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a dictionary once from the triplets (or create your triplets directly in this format). Then access the data using the coord tuple as the key (tuples are hashable, so take advantage of that, and dictionary storage ensures proper lookup speed)

```
path = [ (3,4), (4,5) ]
plane = [ (3,4,50), (4,5,75), (6,7,100) ]

plane_dict = {(x,y):z for x,y,z in plane}
```

At this point, `plane_dict = {(4, 5): 75, (6, 7): 100, (3, 4): 50}`

get access to a score:

```
print(plane_dict.get(path[0],0))
```

and to compute the full score:

```
score = sum(plane_dict.get(p,0) for p in path)
```

(so non-matching coord yields 0)

Answer (score 1):

How about if you store plan as a dict mapping point to score like:

```
plane = {(3, 4): 50, (4, 5): 75, (6, 7): 100}
```

Then to score you'd just do something like:

```
score = 0
for p in path:
   score += plane[p]
```

Comment: Yup, @MosesKoledoye's solution works too. Thought it might be easier to understand if it was more explicit but his solution is more "pythony"